# How to handle Json response and How Can I sperate value from this Json response in my terminal window

Tags: python, json, api, response

```
`import requests
from requests.models import Response

api_key = "xxx"
city = "Houston"
Response = requests.get(
    f"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city},us&appid={api_key}")

full_info = (Response.json()["weather"])

print(full_info)`
```

**Output:**

```
{'coord': {'lon': -95.3633, 'lat': 29.7633}, 'weather': [{'id': 800, 'main': 'Clear', 'description': 'clear sky', 'icon': '01n'}], 'base': 'stations', 'main': {'temp': 299.96, 'feels_like': 302.81, 'temp_min': 298.12, 'temp_max': 301.26, 'pressure': 1015, 'humidity': 84}, 'visibility': 10000, 'wind': {'speed': 0.89, 'deg': 231, 
'gust': 4.02}, 'clouds': {'all': 1}, 'dt': 1627897632, 'sys': {'type': 2, 'id': 2006306, 'country': 'US', 'sunrise': 1627904498, 'sunset': 1627953218}, 'timezone': -18000, 'id': 4699066, 'name': 'Houston', 'cod': 200}
```

if I use
`full_info = response.json()["weather"]`

**Output:**
`[{'id': 800, 'main': 'Clear', 'description': 'clear sky', 'icon': '01n'}]`
after checking its type its list
but I am unable to access specific keyvalue Like Main, or description

How I can achieve all value in different variable or can access only which I want

if I try printing using index

```
print(full_info[0])
```

output remains the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `full_info = Response.json()` and then

`print(full_info['weather'][0]['id'])`

Comment: print(full_info[0][1])
KeyError: 1       
its giving key error

Comment: Do ```full_info = Response.json()``` and then
```print(full_info['weather'][0]['id'])``` it should work

Comment: It works Binit
Thanks
And can you please upvote this question?